# Dual Boot Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11 - After logging into Windows, when I restart and log into Ubuntu it will hang after the login screen

Tags: boot, windows, crash

Dual Boot Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11
After logging into Windows, when I restart and log into Ubuntu it will hang after the login screen.  When I do a hard reset and select Ubuntu again, everything seems to work.
Is there anyway I can fix this?  I have a feeling its to do with something to do with Nvidia drivers (I'm using the proprietary ones).

Comment: Is Fast Startup in Windows disabled? Do you restart from Windows or shutdown Windows and start Ubuntu?

Comment: Fast startup for windows is disable.  I have already tried both restarting from windows and also shutting down from windows.  I get the same issues.

Comment: Another thing to note, I have confirmed its a complete hang when I log into Ubuntu.  How I did this is I tried ssh'ing into my computer from another one and there is no connection.